# How to create Date column from month and year given in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a date column which would take 'year' and 'month' and give me a date starts from 1st

```
E_name  s_date      year  month
  a    01-08-2012   2012   MAR
  a    23-06-2012   2010   DEC 
  a    19-03-2020   2020   DEC
  a    14-02-2020   2020   MAR
  b    27-12-2018   2018   DEC
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
E_name  s_date      year  month  Date
  a    01-08-2012   2012   MAR   01-03-2012
  a    23-06-2012   2010   DEC   01-12-2010
  a    19-03-2020   2020   DEC   01-12-2020
  a    14-02-2020   2020   MAR   01-03-2020
  b    27-12-2018   2018   DEC   01-12-2018
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate the `year` and `month` columns and then use `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TO_DATE(month || year, 'MONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American') AS "Date"
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (E_name, s_date, year, month) AS
SELECT 'a', DATE '2012-08-01', 2012, 'MAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2012-06-23', 2010, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2020-03-19', 2020, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2020-02-14', 2020, 'MAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2018-12-27', 2018, 'DEC' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | E_NAME | S_DATE | YEAR | MONTH | Date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 01-08-2012 | 2012 | MAR | 01-03-2012 |
> | a | 23-06-2012 | 2010 | DEC | 01-12-2010 |
> | a | 19-03-2020 | 2020 | DEC | 01-12-2020 |
> | a | 14-02-2020 | 2020 | MAR | 01-03-2020 |
> | b | 27-12-2018 | 2018 | DEC | 01-12-2018 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee1164dc2e4c17cce3e5532a8da9ca06)*